# Azure webapp azure.storage.sharedaccesssignature ImportError

Tags: python, azure, importerror, azure-web-app-service

I was trying publishing my Python-Project to azure, but I got 
**ImportError: No module named 'azure.storage.sharedaccesssignature'**. The Project works fine without virtual environment, with ve it wont work and gives me this error. Yes, all dependencies are in wheelhouse and in the requirements.txt is --find-links wheelhouse. The dependencies are the same in both with or without ve.
`

```
--find-links wheelhouse
Flask==0.12.1
azure-storage-blob==0.37.0
azure-storage-file==0.37.0
azure-storage-queue==0.37.0
azure==2.0.0
azure-storage==0.34.3
azure-batch==4.0.0
azure-mgmt-scheduler==1.1.3
azure-mgmt-storage==1.0.0
```

`
please tell me what information you also need.
Thank you!

EDIT 1:
My Output the the log in Azure:

```
    D:\home\site\wwwroot>cat logs.txt
2017-10-07 16:08:25.674062: wfastcgi.py 2.1.1 started

2017-10-07 16:08:25.689690: Python version: 3.4.1 (v3.4.1:c0e311e010fc, May 18 2014, 10:38:22) [MSC v.1600 32 bit (Intel)]

2017-10-07 16:08:25.689690: wfastcgi.py 2.1.1 initializing

2017-10-07 16:08:25.737007: Activating venv with executable at D:\home\site\wwwroot\env\Scripts\python.exe

2017-10-07 16:08:26.886554: Getting handler main.app

2017-10-07 16:08:31.038583: Error occurred while reading WSGI handler:



Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "D:\Python34\Scripts\wfastcgi.py", line 711, in main

    env, handler = read_wsgi_handler(response.physical_path)

  File "D:\Python34\Scripts\wfastcgi.py", line 568, in read_wsgi_handler

    return env, get_wsgi_handler(handler_name)

  File "D:\Python34\Scripts\wfastcgi.py", line 541, in get_wsgi_handler

    handler = handler()

  File ".\virtualenv_proxy.py", line 93, in get_venv_handler

    handler = get_wsgi_handler(os.getenv('WSGI_ALT_VIRTUALENV_HANDLER'))

  File ".\virtualenv_proxy.py", line 62, in get_wsgi_handler

    raise ValueError('"%s" could not be imported%s' % (handler_name, last_tb))

ValueError: "main.app" could not be imported: Traceback (most recent call last):

  File ".\virtualenv_proxy.py", line 46, in get_wsgi_handler

    handler = __import__(module_name, fromlist=[name_list[0][0]])

  File "D:\home\site\wwwroot\main.py", line 3, in <module>

    from azure.storage.table import TableService, Entity

  File "D:\home\site\wwwroot\env\lib\site-packages\azure\storage\table\__init__.py", line 26, in <module>

    from .tableservice import TableService

  File "D:\home\site\wwwroot\env\lib\site-packages\azure\storage\table\tableservice.py", line 82, in <module>

    from ..sharedaccesssignature import (

ImportError: No module named 'azure.storage.sharedaccesssignature'







StdOut: 



StdErr: 

2017-10-07 16:08:31.055892: Unhandled exception in wfastcgi.py: Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "D:\Python34\Scripts\wfastcgi.py", line 711, in main

    env, handler = read_wsgi_handler(response.physical_path)

  File "D:\Python34\Scripts\wfastcgi.py", line 568, in read_wsgi_handler

    return env, get_wsgi_handler(handler_name)

  File "D:\Python34\Scripts\wfastcgi.py", line 541, in get_wsgi_handler

    handler = handler()

  File ".\virtualenv_proxy.py", line 93, in get_venv_handler

    handler = get_wsgi_handler(os.getenv('WSGI_ALT_VIRTUALENV_HANDLER'))

  File ".\virtualenv_proxy.py", line 62, in get_wsgi_handler

    raise ValueError('"%s" could not be imported%s' % (handler_name, last_tb))

ValueError: "main.app" could not be imported: Traceback (most recent call last):

  File ".\virtualenv_proxy.py", line 46, in get_wsgi_handler

    handler = __import__(module_name, fromlist=[name_list[0][0]])

  File "D:\home\site\wwwroot\main.py", line 3, in <module>

    from azure.storage.table import TableService, Entity

  File "D:\home\site\wwwroot\env\lib\site-packages\azure\storage\table\__init__.py", line 26, in <module>

    from .tableservice import TableService

  File "D:\home\site\wwwroot\env\lib\site-packages\azure\storage\table\tableservice.py", line 82, in <module>

    from ..sharedaccesssignature import (

ImportError: No module named 'azure.storage.sharedaccesssignature'



2017-10-07 16:08:31.069837: wfastcgi.py 2.1.1 closed
```

Comment: Would you please post your complete log info on Kudu?

Answer (score 0):

You're using the storage package 0.37, this class has been moved to azure.storage.common:

https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-python/blob/master/BreakingChanges.md#version-0370

Stick to 0.36 or upgrade your code to use the new naming.